# How can I link to a PDF in the native Banno app

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Clicking our card face in the native app opens our web app in a webview. Our web app has links to PDFs. Clicking these links from the webview doesn't seem to do anything. These links have a `target` of `_blank`. Other links in the app with a `target` of `_blank` seem to work, just not the links to PDFs. And these links to PDFs work in browsers on both mobile and desktop, just not the webview in the app. We're using the `banno-plugin-framework-bridge` for our card face. Do we need to do anything special to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You're running into an area that's a bit challenging, i.e. PDFs within a plugin.

Relevant section from the [Restrictions](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/restrictions/#rendering-pdfs) page:

> PDFs are potentially challenging for plugins.
>
> The iOS operating system includes a built-in PDF renderer. However, you may find multi-page PDFs unscrollable.
>
> The Android operating system does not include a built-in PDF renderer. The operating system relegates PDF rendering to an external app and not all devices have one installed.

While plugins are based on standard HTML, CSS and Javascript, the full complexity of a modern browser is not supported.

You may need to bounce users over to the *actual* browser to render PDF content, e.g. by using the Plugin Bridge's [Embedded Web Browser Links](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/banno-plugin-framework-bridge/#embedded-web-browser-links).

- Using `target="_blank"` *should* hypothetically work. If you're running into issues, there may be something specific in how your web server is configured to handle serving up PDF content. That may very well be worth your time to investigate, given that you describe successful behavior with *other* links and it's *only* PDFs which have weird behavior.